# NuxtJS - where to store constants?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, constants, nuxt.js

Where is the best place to keep const? I need to store e.g. key-pair objects to easily replace id with a name.

Example:

```
const guildNames = {
   1: 'Leader',
   2: 'Vide-Leader'
   3: 'Member'
}
```

Is vuex a good place? If not, please show me a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like the practice of putting them into their own file:

```js
// GuildNames.js
const LEADER = 1;
const VIDE_LEADER = 2;
const MEMBER = 3;

export default { LEADER, VIDE_LEADER, MEMBER };
```

And then to use it:

```js
// App.js
import { LEADER } from "./GuildNames";
// or
import guilds from "./GuildNames";
const leader = guilds.LEADER
```